# SQL query to join smae table multiple times

Tags: sql, db2

I have a scenario to join the same table multiple times to get the desired output. For ex I have two tables TABLE A and TABLE B.

[image]

[image]

- Step 1: I want to take the all the parties from TABLE A which have
  lowest Idate. Lowest idate will be fetched based partyid and idate
  column.
- Step 2: Then based on CID which is fetched from  TABLE A in step 1,
  we need to fetch the corresponding MID from TABLE B which have
  MIDTYPE=130300.
- Step 3: Then based on the MID fetched in step 2 we need to traverse
  the same table and find out the latest record for the same MID based
  on idate in TABLE B and fetch the corresponding CID for the MID.
- Step 4: Now for that CID we need to fetch MID value for MIDTYPE
  130307 in the same table(TABLEB). And my final output should be combination of MID
  which we fetched for step 3 and MID fetched for 130307 in step 4.

I write a query like this ..but its taking lot of time for the query to run as we are going through the same table(TABLEB) multiple times and TABLEB have millions of rows. Is there anyway we can rewrite this query in different way. Could some one can help with this me.

```
SELECT
    ident.mid mid1,
    b.mid mid2
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            tableb
        WHERE
            midtype = 130307
    ) ident
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            s.cid,
            s.mid,
            s.midtype
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    cid,
                    partyid,
                    admin_sys_tp_cd,
                    mid,
                    ilast
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            cq.cid,
                            RANK() OVER(
                                PARTITION BY cq.partyid
                                ORDER BY
                                    cq.idate ASC
                            ) rnk,
                            cq.idate,
                            cq.partyid,
                            i.mid,
                            i.idate AS ilast
                        FROM
                            tablea cq
                            INNER JOIN tableb i ON cq.cid = i.cid
                            INNER JOIN tablec ON i.cid = c.cid
                        WHERE
                            i.midtype = 130300
                    )
                WHERE
                    rnk = 1
            ) a
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT
                            cid,
                            mid,
                            midtype,
                            RANK() OVER(
                                PARTITION BY mid
                                ORDER BY
                                    idate DESC
                            ) rnk_mpid
                        FROM
                            tableb
                    )
                WHERE
                    rnk_mpid = 1
            ) s ON a.mid = s.mid
                   AND s.midtype = 130300
    ) b ON ident.cid = b.cid
           AND ident.midtype = 130307
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

not what you asked, but before others and I,  spent time trying to get different approaches for you, let's make sure the basics are covered.

No matter how different you can write an SQL query,  they will never perform fast,  in a MILLION base table if you don't have the proper indexes for it.  Specially in your case,  as you have to access it 3 times at least.

Just by looking at your detailed steps. I would say that you should have at least 3 different indexes created to support this query.

```
TableA_Index1 ( PARTYID, LDATE,  INCLUDES CID) 
TableB_Index1 (CID, MIDTYPE, INCLUDES MID ) 
TableB_Index2 (MID, LDATE, INCLUDES CID )
```

Do you have them ? 
Have you ever tried to run this query on db2-advisor (db2advis)  to get recommended indexes for it ?